# Erro de serialização ao carregar gráfico do google charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-charts

Tenho o método `JsonResult` chamado "CarregarChart" que retorna um `DataTable` para uma requisição `Ajax` onde estou tentando popular dados em um [gráfico do google charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart), e o problema é que ocorre o seguinte erro: 
 `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.` 
**Dúvida:** Como contornar esse erro e carregar o gráfico corretamente ?

```
public JsonResult CarregarChart(DashboardSaleBySupervisor model)
        {
            string mensagem = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
                dt1.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));
                dt1.Columns.Add("Sales", typeof(int));
                dt1.Columns.Add("Expenses", typeof(int));
                dt1.Columns.Add("Profit", typeof(int));

                dt1.Rows.Add(2014, 1000, 400, 200);
                dt1.Rows.Add(2015, 1170, 460, 250);
                dt1.Rows.Add(2016, 660, 1120, 300);
                dt1.Rows.Add(2017, 1030, 540, 350);

                return Json(new { success = true, message = mensagem, list = dt1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error(ex);
                return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

**AJAX:**

```
function CarregarChart(url) {

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: null,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {

                var list = response.list;
                google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['bar'] });
                google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

                function drawChart() {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(list);
                    var options = {
                        chart: {
                            title: 'Company Performance',
                            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
                        }
                    };
                    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('Chart'));
                    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
                }

        }
    });
};
```

Comment: `DataTable`? pra que usar um objeto complexo desse só pra retornar alguns valores, faria mais sentido uma classe com as 4 propriedades e retonar uma `List` dessa classe

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual obrigado pelo comentário mas esse não é o alvo do post, esse código é um exemplo que usei para deixar o código mais limpo e fácil entendimento pois na prática o Banco de Dados vai retornar uma quantidade de colunas diferentes a cada chamada de forma dinâmica em virtude da procedure usar o comando Pivot por isso que optei usar o objeto DataTable .

Comment: *"esse código é um exemplo que usei para deixar o código mais limpo"* neste caso fica mais difícil de ajudar, precisa ter uma ideia de como está o código real. Com esse código o erro acontece? Acredito que saiba o que significa o erro de referencia circular ao fazer o serialize, então o problema está relacionado à serialização desse DataTable, então me parece que a minha sugestão, ao menos para fazer um debug, é bem pertinente :)

Comment: Como o Ricardo comentou, se o problema não está no código apresentando, esse erro não pode ser reproduzido. Sem ver o código real não dá adivinhar onde está o erro... Na verdade pelo erro dá sim, mas sem ver a estrutura de verdade não dá para ajudar